# Ember js version 1: Route hierarchy / activation

Tags: ember.js

We have a scenario along these lines:

Quote
--->Create

So route names `quote` and `quote.create`.

The issue is that we need to render the templates into the main outlet.  So in our main route (that all other are inherited from) we have this:

`renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({ into: 'application' });
    }`

When I navigate to `quote` it renders the quote view.  From there I navigate to `quote.create` and it renders the create view.  However, going *back* to `quote` from `quote.create` renders nothing.

How can I get around this?

When I go back to the \quote url route 'quote.index' is sought.  Since it is defined 'automagically' nothing happens.  When I define the route explicitly ember tries to find the `quote.index` template and view and *these* do not exist.

A workaround I tried is to have this:

`App.QuoteIndex{Route|Controller|View} = App.Quote{Route|Controller|View}.extend()`

**EDIT**:

Hey diddle-diddle, here is my fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/Mf5Dj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember.js does not rerender a parent view when transitioning to a parent route, so using into with a parent view template is not recommended.

There is an easier way to create what you are trying to: use a quote/index route:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Rendering Issue</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="quote">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="quote/index">
    <h2>Quote View</h2>
    {{#linkTo 'quote.create'}}Create a new quote{{/linkTo}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="quote/create">
    <h2>Quote Create View</h2>
    <p>Some controls would go here.</p>
     {{#linkTo 'quote'}}Go back to quote view{{/linkTo}}
</script>

App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function () {
        this.transitionTo('quote');
    }
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('quote', function () {
        this.route('create');
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/eYYnz/

Comment: Ah, I see.  So basically one steers clear of the parent (quote in this case) and just use the 'sub' routes (index and create in this case).  I'm going to give it a bash tomorrow.  If it pans out I'll accept the answer.

Comment: This works fine but it does not work when the quote template is pre-compiled.  For the pre-compiled template it seems to go into some endless loop trying to locate the outlet.  Any ideas?

Comment: OK, so it seems we had an error in our pre-compiler :) --- sorted.  Thanks for your.  Have some points on me!